# unable to understand Core java for loop and switch case statement logic

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

Here is my question. whats the use of `{j++;}` in the following code and why if i comment  `{j++;}` though j = 0 why its not going inside case(0). Output of answer without `{j++;}` line is 0. Why not 1.

```
class Strings {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, j = 0;
        for (i = 10; i < 0; i--) {
            j++;
        }
        switch (j) {
            case (0):
                j = j + 1;
            case (1):
                j = j + 2;
                break;
            case (2):
                j = j + 3;
                break;
            case (10):
                j = j + 10;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `break;` after case 0, so case 1 is used also.

Comment: at least  you would have debug it once.

Comment: If you get 0 as your output and not 3, please show us what you commented. Is it just the line `j++;` or the entire body of the loop, i.e. `{ j++; }`? If so, the switch statement is never run, because it then would be the body of the loop, which never runs due to the error in the loop condition.

Comment: If you remove `{j++}` the `for` takes the whole statement `switch` to loop.

Comment: MyBad! I overlooked the for condition and made me to stuck. Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because there is no break statement .and it goes to 0 case and 1 case .putting `System.out.println()` inside of cases you can find the happening thing yourself

```
initially j is zero . because you for loop not run as condition is false (10<1) is false.

case (0) : //goes inside of this case because j==0;
j=j+1;

//now j is 1 and goes to  case 1

case (1):  //goes to this case too
j = j + 2; //now j is 3
break;     //exit from here
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop will never run since you set i to 10 and enter the loop only if i is smaller than 0

Answer (score 1):

It does go into case 0, but when you miss a "break" statement you just keep executing what's below, until you hit a break, so in this case when j == 0 you execute both case 0 and case 1.

```
class Strings {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     int i,j=0;
         for(i=10;i<0;i--)
         { j++; }
         switch(j) {
         case (0) :
         j=j+1;
         break;    
         case(1):
         j=j+2;
         break;
         case (2) :
             j=j+3;
         break;
         case (10) :
             j=j+10;
             break;
         default :
             break;
         }

         System.out.println(j);
       }
}
```

This does what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

`j++` is equals to `j = j+1` or `j += 1`
In this case the for loop is executed 10 times so after that you have `j == 10`
Moreover, you have to insert a `break` in the first `case` statement. In fact once the `switch` recognizes that you variable is equals to 0, it executes the first two statements (until he finds a `break`)

Answer (score 0):

`Jagadish`:

Recommend you use `Toggle Breakpoint` and view  variables changement,like`i`,`j` in Eclipse.
[image]